# Remove preceding whitespace within textarea tags in html content

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-form

For my Zend Framework library i have this view-helper that indents code.

**I have added the solution in the code below**

```
<?php

class My_View_Helper_Indent
{

    function indent($indent, $string, $space = ' ')
    {
        if($string == '') {
            return '';
        }
        $indent = str_repeat($space, $indent);
        $content = $indent . str_replace("\n", "\n" . $indent, rtrim($string)) . PHP_EOL;           

// BEGIN SOLUTION TO PROBLEM
// Based on user CodeAngry's answer
$callback = function($matches) use ($indent) {
    $matches[2] = str_replace("\n" . $indent, "\n", $matches[2]);
    return '<textarea' . $matches[1] . '>' . $matches[2] . '</textarea>';
};
$content = preg_replace_callback('~<textarea(.*?)>(.*?)</textarea>~si', $callback, $content);       
// END 

        return $content;
    }
}
```

And with the following test code..

```
$content = 'This is some text' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '<div>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '  Text inside div, indented' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '<form>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '  <ul>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '    <li>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '      <label>inputfield</label>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '      <input type="text" />' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '    </li>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '    <li>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '      <textarea cols="80" rows="10">' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= 'content of text area' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '   this line is intentionally indented with 3 whitespaces' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= 'content of text area' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '      </textarea>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '    </li>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '  </ul>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= '</form>' . PHP_EOL;
$content .= 'The end';

echo $this->view->indent (6, $content);
```

What i would like to do, is to remove X whitespace characters from lines with the textarea tags. Where X matches the number of spaces that the code was indented, in the example above it's 6 spaces.

Comment: in other words you want to remove all the spaces before `<textarea>`?

Comment: No, only the whitespace that are added by my indent function.. Let's say user intentionally indented a line in the textarea before submitting the form, and the form is redisplayed because of an error, then i don't want those intentional added whitespace to disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$html = preg_replace('~<textarea(.*?)>\s*(.*?)\s*</textarea>~si',
    '<textarea$1>$2</textarea>', $html);
```

Try this regular expression. Should trim the contents of your `textarea` contents. *Is this what you need?*

**OR**:

```
$html = preg_replace_callback('~<textarea(.*?)>(.*?)</textarea>~si', function($matches){
    $matches[2] = trim($matches[2]); // trim 2nd capture (inner textarea)
    return "<textarea{$matches[1]}>{$matches[2]}</textarea>";
}, $html);
```

Comment: I tried your regex against my test code (updated with cols and rows attributes after you answer). And it returns this `<textarea> cols="80" row="10"</textarea>`

Comment: I fixed you regex by setting the replace part to `<textarea$1>$2</textarea>`.. However it doesn't give me the desired result.

Comment: @Phliplip Fixed it, sorry :) Try now.

Comment: Correct to replace the + to * in your first match, but i think my above fix is still required to keep attributes in the tag ;-) But in regards to my question, with your regex the 6 space indention is still added, except for the very first line in the textarea, which now starts right after the textarea begin tag.

Comment: @Phliplip It's late, I'm tired and watching a movie:) I've already captured them, just forgot them on the way... Fixed it.

Comment: +1 for SO'ing so late, while being tired and watching a movie :)
Also please read my comment to Casimir in the OP

Comment: @Phliplip Well... have fun with it as I don't understand your question. So you have intentional indents and the input can have indents and you want to separate them... **INCEPTION style! A dream within a dream...**

Comment: @CodeAgnry I got a solution to my problem thanks to your answer, i have added it the OP